# Can't repaint a JPanel while my program is busy

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm trying to make a visualization of algorithms. I had a working program, but is was really dirty and I decided to re-orgranize it before I continued. The problem is that it won't repaint anymore before the algorithm finishes. (and I have tried using revalidate instead/in combination with repaint)

The option menu:

```
public class BootScreen extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();

SpinnerNumberModel arraySizeModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(50, 0, 100000, 1);
SpinnerNumberModel speedModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(20, 0, 10000, 1);
SpinnerNumberModel algSelectModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(1, 1, 5, 1);

JSpinner arraySizeSpinner = new JSpinner(arraySizeModel);
JSpinner speedSpinner = new JSpinner(speedModel);
JSpinner algSelectSpinner = new JSpinner(algSelectModel);

JButton start = new JButton("Start");

BootScreen() {
    frame.setTitle("Settings");
    frame.setSize(500, 250);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);

    //just creating the options menu, nothing special here (deleted for simplicity)
    //...
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(Integer.parseInt(arraySizeModel.getValue().toString()), Integer.parseInt
            (speedModel.getValue().toString()));

    switch(Integer.parseInt(algSelectModel.getValue().toString())) {
        case 1:
            alg.alg1();
            break;

        case 2:
            alg.alg2();
            break;

        case 3:
            alg.alg3();
            break;

        case 4:
            alg.alg4();
            break;

        case 5:
            alg.alg5();
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] Args) {new BootScreen();}
}
```

The main algorithm stuffs:

```
public class Algorithm {
int[] A;
GUI gui;
int type;
int[] pointers;
int delay;
int max;

Random r = new Random();

Algorithm( int arraySize, int delaySet) {
    A = new int[arraySize];
    delay = delaySet;
    gui = new GUI(this);
}

void generate(int maxIntSize, int pointersAmount, int typeSet) {
    max = maxIntSize;
    for( int i = 0; i < A.length; i++ ) {
        A[i] = r.nextInt(max);
    }

    pointers = new int[pointersAmount];
    for( int i = 0; i < pointers.length; i++ ) {
        pointers[i] = -1;
    }
    type = typeSet;
}

void step(boolean sleep, int updatePointer, int updatePointerVal) {
    pointers[updatePointer] = updatePointerVal;
    gui.revalidate();
    gui.repaint();
    if( sleep ) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
        }catch( InterruptedException e ) {
        }
    }
}

//alg1(), alg2(), .... would be here. They first call generate() and call step() a couple of times. (deleted for simplicity)
}
```

The GUI:

```
public class GUI extends JPanel {
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Algorithm alg;

GUI( Algorithm algIn ) {
    alg = algIn;

    frame.setTitle("Algorithmizer");
    frame.setSize(1080, 720);
    frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(this);
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //drawing alg.A as a bar-graph by looping through it (deleted for simplicity)
}
}
```

When I put System.out.println("1") before the repaint() call, System.out.println("2") in the paintComponent() function and System.out.println("3") after the repaint() call it will only print:
1
3
1
3
1
3
...
I also tried printing the stack, didn't get anything usefull from that either. 
The program does repaint when the algorithm is done, but that isn't usefull to me.

Comment: Id suggest not doing any heavy lifting without using a SwingWorker

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take an approach like this. This will do all your calculations and stuff in a worker thread off the Event Dispatch Thread, and then call done() where you can do you GUI updates on the Event Dispatch Thread.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
    new SwingWorker<Object, Object>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                runAlg();
                return null
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                //any of you gui stuff here
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}

public void runAlg(){
     Algorithm alg = new Algorithm(Integer.parseInt(arraySizeModel.getValue().toString()), Integer.parseInt
            (speedModel.getValue().toString()));

    switch(Integer.parseInt(algSelectModel.getValue().toString())) {
        case 1:
            alg.alg1();
            break;

        case 2:
            alg.alg2();
            break;

        case 3:
            alg.alg3();
            break;

        case 4:
            alg.alg4();
            break;

        case 5:
            alg.alg5();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that it won't repaint anymore before the algorithm finishes.

Your algorithm is executing on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` which is the Thread the GUI uses to paint itself, therefore the GUI can't repaint itself until the algorithm is finished.

The solution is to use a separate Thread for the algorithm.

One way to do this is to use a `Swing Worker` which executes on a separate Thread and allows you to "publish" results as the algorithm is executing.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more details. The tutorial has a Swing Worker example.